# Australia ETA (Evisitor)

Tags: visas, international-travel, australia, dutch-citizens, eta

I received an Australian Electronic Travel Authority (ETA) issued for a planned visit to Australia. I am scheduled to fly tomorrow.

My family name as listed on my ETA shows a hyphen. My actual family name doesn't have a hyphen. I read somewhere that I should request a new ETA, because of that discrepancy, so that's what i did. I have also read that once I request a new ETA, it will only be granted after my old ETA has expired, as well as that my old ETA is no longer valid as of the day I request a new one. Now this is confusing me. Does this mean they won't process my new ETA and my old one is now invalid?

I checked with vevo and it seems that my old visa is still in effect. Should I remove my new application?

Comment: Edit it seems im holding a evisitor visa and not a ETA, im from holland (Netherlands)

Answer (score 3):

Your airline will check your visa before you fly out, and they can actually help you resolve it on the spot, if it's going to be an issue.  I flew to Australia last November with a visa tied to an expired passport, and the United Airlines Gate Agent at LAX was able to call someone in Australia and get my visa updated to my new current passport.  Hopefully if the hyphenated name is enough to cause a problem, they will sort you out before it's a show stopper.